# How to add Javascript code into a block

Tags: blocks, javascript

I have a Drupal 7 site. I'd like to add Social Media follow buttons
(i.e. Follow us on Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin). 
I grabbed some Javascript code from http://www.addthis.com
 which generates these buttons and also links to some analytics services I will be using.
Now I need to figure out how to place the AddThis Javascript code I generated, to a Drupal block. Once it's in a block, it will be easy for me to move around my Drupal site pages.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [addthis module](https://drupal.org/project/addthis) rather than adding a block. If you however want to add a block, just go to **admin/structure/block** click on add block. Paste your script in and select filter type of php code and click save

If you do not have PHP filter in the filter type, enable it under the core module

Comment: The other alternative is creating a custom block in a custom module, but the addthis module works fine for most cases.

Comment: Just to mention that save php into the DB is not a good choice. DB should store content and not the system logic.

Comment: The addthis module is for sharing buttons, not for "Follow us" buttons. Perhaps I missed something when I installed and played with the module.

Comment: 4life, you're solution was simple and it worked perfectly. I just added a block, selected PHP and pasted in the javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, in order to add Social Media follow buttons you can use the Follow module.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Social Media follow buttons you can use the [Follow](https://drupal.org/project/follow) module. If you need to add Social Media share buttons you can use the [AddThis](https://drupal.org/project/addthis) module or the [Easy Social](https://drupal.org/project/easy_social) module.

To attach CSS or JS files to a specific block you will need to build a custom module that implements the [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) to manipulate the block render array and then use [Drupal 7 FAPI's #attached attribute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) to attach the file to the block.

Comment: The addthis module is for share buttons, not for follow us buttons. Perhaps I missed something.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the answer to add the module for follow buttons.

Comment: Also, I'm sticking with the Addthis code, I'm glad to know about the Follow module and I'm sure others reading this thread will want to know about.